# Using Outlook for mail client and getting error 0x800CCC05 when tyring to sync

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have Windows 10, outlook 2010 and cannot sync to my subscribed folders. Am getting error 0x800CCC05.

Answer (score 0):

One highly-voted solution in [this similar thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/e7fb7a16-d7c4-4f5c-ae18-944277e0e307/error-synchronizing-subscribed-folders-in-ms-outlook-2010?forum=outlook):

1. Navigate to File > Options > Advanced.
2. Scroll down to the send/receive section and click on the send/receive button.
3. On the right-hand side of the send/receive groups window, click on the Edit button
4. Un-check the "Get folder unread count for subscribed folders"
5. Under Received mail items, check the option "User the custom behavior defined below"
6. In the window below that displays your Gmail folders, just select inbox and leave the others unchecked
7. Click Ok and then exit out of options and perform a send/receive to test if it is now working